# Zeptosecond smallest unit of time ever measured? How?

Tags: time, si-units, metrology

There is this newly discovered zeptosecond discovered by scientists. I have seen some articles calling it smallest unit of time ever measured. How can it be possible if Yoctosecond already exists which is smaller than it.
Can someone explain this?

Here are links to some of the articles:

[BBC News: Zeptosecond - the smallest time unit ever measured](https://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/54631056)

[LiveScience: Meet the zeptosecond, the shortest unit of time ever measured](https://www.livescience.com/zeptosecond-shortest-time-unit-measured.html)

[Smithsonian Magazine: Meet the Zeptosecond, the Smallest Slice of Time Yet Recorded](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/physicists-record-smallest-slice-time-yet-180961085/)

Answer (score 2):

The articles says researchers looked at shift in an interference pattern, in which the two (secondary) sources where hydrogen atoms (in a H$_2$ molecule), and the shift can be attributed to the time delay the incident light (a photon) takes to cross the interatomic distance (0.074 nm), (See figure). That time is:

[image]

$$ \Delta t = \frac{0.074\,{\rm nm}} c \approx 2.47 \times 10^{-19}\,{\rm s} = 247\,{\rm zs}$$

They aren't really measuring clock tics with that period, rather, they are observing an effect that directly depends on that time period.

With that criterion, one could say the width of an unstable particle is a measurement time via:

$$ \Gamma = \Delta Mc^2 = \frac {\hbar} {\tau} $$

where ${\tau}$ is the mean lifetime. A classic example is the delta baryon, which is produced by scattering pions off of protons (or neutrons), e.g.:

$$ \pi^+ + p \rightarrow \Delta^{++} \rightarrow \pi^+ + p $$

[image]

The existence of the intermediate resonant state causes an increase in the scattering cross section when the center-of-mass energy of initial particles matches the delta's mass ($M=1232$ MeV), which is not exact...it varies by the width $\Gamma=112$ MeV.

The lifetime is around 5 ys, or roughly the time it takes light to cross a proton.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can *define* units of time as small as we like, and give them names as we like. A zeptosecond is $10^{-21}$ second, but we can just as easily define a tenth of a zeptosecond or a thousandth of a zeptosecond (which is $10^{-24}$ seconds or one yoctosecond) or one millionth of a zeptosecond - which we could call a microzeptosecond or a milliyoctosecond. Neither the zeptosecond nor the yoctosecond are discovered - they are just defined.

Whether it is possible to measure such small amounts of time once we have named them is another matter. The articles that you link to are about the first successful *measurement* of intervals of a few hundred zeptoseconds.